# Android IPC, Service Not Getting Instantiated

Tags: android, android-service, ipc, aidl

I have a Service which resides inside a lib project like this

```
public abstract class MyService extends Service{
    //service body here 
}
```

I have my aidl file set up to communicate with the remote service which also included in the lib project copying the aidl file here

```
package mypackage;

// Declare the communication interface which holds all of our exposed functions.
interface IMyService {
    //interface body here 
}
```

Inside the lib manifest I have declared the service like this

```
<service
    android:name="mypackage.core.MyService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:process=":remote" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="mypackage.IMyService" />
    </intent-filter>

</service>
```

I have included this lib in my app but when I try to bind the service from the app it is not getting instantiated. Can any one suggest me what I am doing wrong and if so guid me a way out. The service in is starting inside another class which belongs to the lib like this

```
try{
    Intent i = new Intent(MyService.class.getName());
    i.setPackage("mypackage");
    // start the service explicitly.
    // otherwise it will only run while the IPC connection is up.       
    mAppContext.startService(i);
    boolean ret = mAppContext.bindService(i,
            mConnection, Service.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    if(!ret){
        MyLogger.log("Error");
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    MyLogger.log("err");
}
```

The service bound API always returns false what would be the issue. Is this the prominent way of creating a RemoteService ? Do I need to add this service in the app manifest if so how ?

Comment: Is your lib manifest getting correctly merged into you main one?  You might want to use reverse engineering tools to dump out the manifest of the compiled APK and see that it makes it there.  Also, watch logcat during the run attempt and see what the error is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> what would be the issue

First, your `Intent` does not match your `<service>`.

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyService.class.getName());
```

You are passing in an action `String` that looks something like `mypackage.core.MyService`. However, that is not the `<action>` for your `Service`:

```
<action android:name="mypackage.IMyService" />
```

Hence, your `Intent` is not matching anything, and you cannot bind.

---

Second, your `Service` is *very* insecure. Any app that wants to can bind to it. If you want other apps to bind to it, that's fine, but *please* secure it with some permission, so the user gets a vote for what apps can bind to it.

---

Third, you are binding using an implicit `Intent`, one that uses stuff like an action string. That won't work on Android 5.0+, as you can no longer bind to a service using an implicit `Intent`. Using an implicit `Intent` to discover a service is fine, but you then need to convert the `Intent` to an explicit one, that incorporates the component name. Here is how I do this in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Binding/Remote/Client):

```
  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity host) {
    super.onAttach(host);

    appContext=(Application)host.getApplicationContext();

    Intent implicit=new Intent(IDownload.class.getName());
    List<ResolveInfo> matches=host.getPackageManager()
                                  .queryIntentServices(implicit, 0);

    if (matches.size()==0) {
      Toast.makeText(host, "Cannot find a matching service!",
                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if (matches.size()>1) {
      Toast.makeText(host, "Found multiple matching services!",
                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {
      Intent explicit=new Intent(implicit);
      ServiceInfo svcInfo=matches.get(0).serviceInfo;
      ComponentName cn=new ComponentName(svcInfo.applicationInfo.packageName,
                                         svcInfo.name);

      explicit.setComponent(cn);
      appContext.bindService(explicit, this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
  }
```

---

> Is this the prominent way of creating a RemoteService ?

Few people create remote services. They are difficult to secure, difficult to deal with version changes in protocol, etc. And, in your case, I do not know why you think you need a remote service, since you are clearly binding to the service from your own app.

Comment: _Third, you are binding using an implicit Intent, one that uses stuff like an action string. That won't work on Android 5.0+, as you can no longer bind to a service using an implicit Intent._ Is the `Intent` considered implicit if the package name and action are set, but the component name is missing?

Comment: @Vikram: AFAIK that should still be implicit.

Comment: I can see what you mean. An application can have multiple services with identical `intent-filters`. But then, I came across `ContextImpl#validateServiceIntent(Intent)`. Looks like its considering the above scenario to be explicit enough.

Comment: @Vikram: Interesting! I'm pretty sure the definition of explicit `Intent` means that it has the `ComponentName`, but I agree that `validateServiceIntent()` seems happy enough with `setPackage()`. Good to know -- thanks!